# Can I use clips inside mechanism to create my custom cod parser?

Tags: parsing, translation, context-free-grammar, clips, expert-system

For purposes of creating knowledge editor I want to parse clips rules and than represent it in a more appreciate way. Any help will be valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function called check-syntax (and C API equivalent CheckSyntax) that can tell you whether a construct is semantically correct:

```
CLIPS> (check-syntax "(deftemplate point (slot x) (slot y))")
FALSE
CLIPS> (check-syntax "(defrule print (point (slot ?x) (slot ?y)) =>)")
("
[PRNTUTIL2] Syntax Error:  Check appropriate syntax for defrule.

ERROR:
(defrule MAIN::print
   (point (
" FALSE)
CLIPS>
```

The function, however, can not distinguish between a syntactically incorrect and semantically incorrect construct. In the example above, the deftemplate point is semantically and syntactically correct. The print rule is syntactically correct, but not semantically correct because the point deftemplate has not been defined.

Appendix G of the Basic Programming Guide has the CLIPS BNF, so if you want to create a parser that checks syntax, that's a good starting point.